# NodeJS socket.io-server doesn't fire 'disconnect' or 'close' events when client out of internet

Tags: disconnect

NodeJS socket.io-server doesn't fire 'disconnect' or 'close' events when client out of internet.The server could not listen 'disconnect' when client out of internet.How to do it????

Answer (score 0):

when client is out of internet socket.io fire disconnect event after some time go to node_modules -> socket.io -> lib -> manager.js edit your 
 'close timeout'  , 'heartbeat interval' , 'heartbeat timeout' values according to your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

The [migration doc](http://socket.io/docs/migrating-from-0-9/) didn't meet expectations, they said the are providing *backward compatibility for heartbeat timeout and heartbeat interval*, http://socket.io/docs/migrating-from-0-9/#configuration-differences

But it didn't work for me..

So guys please use this in latest version of socketio

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(httpd, {
log: true,
"transports":["polling"],
"pingInterval":10000,
"pingTimeout":15000
});
```